# start from first space before the value

Tags: awk, text-processing

I don't know how i can say "start from first space before the value" or "Closest space before the word".
my code like (linux bash awk):

```
data= "your website is the best website"
value = "t w"
```

when i used this code to print the line from value to end of line:

```
if ( index($0, value))
    print substr($0, index($0,value))
```

the result was:

```
t website
```

please  i want to print it like:

```
best website
```

to print from the word which containt first letter?

Comment: Why your output is NOT `website the best website`? since website and the also have t in them. Kindly do elaborate more on same.

Comment: Because it searches for two consecutive letters, t then w.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk, build a regex that adds "non-blanks" before and after the `value`

```bash
gawk 'BEGIN {
    data = "your website is the best website"
    value = "t w"
    regex = "[^[:blank:]]+" value "[^[:blank:]]+"
    if (match(data, regex, m)) {print m[0]}
}'
```

```
best website
```

With any awk, use the RSTART and RLENGTH variables set by the match(str, re) function:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {
    data = "your website is the best website"
    value = "t w"
    regex = "[^[:blank:]]+" value "[^[:blank:]]+"
    if (match(data, regex)) {print substr(data, RSTART, RLENGTH)}
}'
```

Or, don't treat `value` as a regex: use `index()` and look backwards and forwards for spaces that delimit the words:

````bash
awk 'BEGIN {
    data = "your website is the best website"
    value = "t w"
    start = index(data, value)
    if (start > 0) {
        i = start; while (i > 0 && substr(data, i, 1) != " ") {i--}
        j = start + length(data); while (j < length(data) && substr(data, j, 1) != " ") {j++}
        print substr(data, i+1, j-i+1)
    }
}'```
````

Comment: thanks mr.glenn, 2nd code work with me.   sometime data containt number, please how i can print it in the last, i test this code: gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/, "", $0) but not work ?

Comment: I recommend asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk -v RS='\\s*\\S+t w\\S+' 'RT{sub(/^\s+/,"",RT);print RT}' Input_file
```

***OR*** in case you want to pass a variable as an Input to `awk` command try following then:

```bash
awk -v RS='\\s*\\S+t w\\S+' 'RT{sub(/^\s+/,"",RT);print RT}' <<< "$data"
```

Comment: thnks but you used t w, this examle, i tested it by "value" in up, but not work with me, regards.

Comment: @lightspeedinrunway, could you please elaborate more on example for which it's not working, thank you.

Comment: ok, i added more code up.

Comment: @lightspeedinrunway, With your shown samples its working fine for me, kindly do let me know on which part its not working, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> echo "your website is the best website" | 
>
> mawk 'sub(".+ ","&"_,$(NF-!__))+sub("^[^"_"]*"_,__)' \_='\3' FS='t w' OFS='t w'
> ```

```
best website
```